# Can't find a "standard" group corresponding to $f(\mathbf{F})=\overline{\left( \mathbf{F}^T\mathbf{F} \right)} \left(\mathbf{F}^T\mathbf{F} \right)$

Tags: group-theory

Let $f:\mathbb{C}^n\to\mathbb{R}$

$$
f(\mathbf{F})=\overline{\left( \mathbf{F}^T\mathbf{F} \right)} \left(\mathbf{F}^T\mathbf{F} \right)
$$

The invariance is

$$
f(\mathbf{F})=f(M\mathbf{F})
$$

where $M$ is an $n \times n$ matrix with complex entries.

---

Injecting $M$ into $f$, I get:

$$
\begin{align}
f(M\mathbf{F})&= \overline{\left( (M\mathbf{F})^T M\mathbf{F} \right)} \left( (M\mathbf{F})^T M\mathbf{F} \right)\\
&=\overline{\left(\mathbf{F}^TM^TM\mathbf{F}\right)}\left(\mathbf{F}^TM^TM\mathbf{F}\right)
\end{align}
$$

At first, I was thinking "well, it obvious if $M^TM=I$ then $f(M\mathbf{F})=f(\mathbf{F})$ and therefore its $O(n)$". However, then I realized that $M$ is a complex matrix, and $O(n)$ is over real matrices. So I considered $O(n,\mathbb{C})$, but still, there is a more general invariance:

If $M^TM=zI$, where $z\in \mathbb{C}$ and further that $z^*z=1$, then we still have $f(M\mathbf{F})=f(\mathbf{F})$.

So it produces a mixture of orthogonality and unitary. Any idea where this invariance group fits into the classification of groups?

Can I write the group as $O(n,\mathbb{C})\times U(1)$, or other somesuch language?